# Get columnnumber of selected column in TableViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a table with `m*n` rows.
I have used `TableViewer` ,`TableViewerColumn` of `JFace` and have added editing support to each column.

I am **not using** any **Databinding**.

I can get the row number of the edited cell from `TableViewer.getTable().getSelectionIndices()`
How can I get the column number of the editing cell?

Comment: Which version of eclipse is this?

Comment: If you use a separate editing support class for each column you know which column you are in just by the class that is active.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `CellEditor::activate(ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent)`.

The source of the event that is passed to `activate` is a `ViewerCell`. Finally, `ViewerCell::getColumnIndex()` denotes the column number which is currently being edited.

This approach, however, requires the cell editor to be activated before the column number information is available.